# Synchronization engine with insufficient permissions

Tags: identity

I have this question that desperately needs an answer. I have been struggling with this issue for weeks.
I get a set of users synched into metaverse with a attribute (let's call it AppUser set to true/false). What I want to do is that when the user is created in FIM I want FIM to look at this value and put the user in a specific set. I have tried to use criteria-based membership on the set. This doesn't work for me. I could be doing it the wrong way or it could have something to do do with MPR.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the right one, so it should work fine that way.

However, be advised that the list of members of a set is rebuilt once a day, as far as I  have noticed. You can preview the list directly in the set and should be able to see them (as the request is done dynamicly in this case).